# Store log from opera dragonfly console

Tags: opera, opera-dragonfly

Do you know about some way how to save log from Opera Dragonfly console ?
I did not find any, neither plugin for that.
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like the only option for now is to select all text and copy/paste it somewhere.

Comment: not good enough for me. I am working with more than 200 000 lines of log daily, that needs to be parsed and then saved in DBS. Woring on my own opera extension now, that would provide funcions I need.

Comment: You should seriously think about developing a custom log solution then. A simple php script (or in whatever language you prefer) which takes care of one or more log files.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a preference in opera:config, it's under "User Prefs" and is named "Console Error Log Enabled". Here you can also control where it is saved and what type of errors Opera will include when it is saved: 
opera:config#UserPrefs|ConsoleErrorLog

Comment: Good idea, but it is not it. Opera error log is not the same as Dragonfly console. I will get through that settings, maybe I find console. Thanks so far.

Comment: What content do you want to save from the DF console that is not in the error log?

Comment: when .js puts `console.log("");` it goes only to console. So anything that is logged I wanted to have in file. But I already solve it otherway. Thanks.

Comment: console.log('') content is logged to file for me. Sure it doesn't work? Also, if you solved the problem please answer your question yourself and accept the answer so that other people with the same issue can find the way to do it here.

Comment: Well, console log was just part of problem and one of ways how to make it done. I did it other way, still can not log from console. But project as whole works already for a several days :) I have stopped my efforts to put the log to file, otherwise I would put here some tutorial how to do that.